# listbox ложное действие

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

При нажатии на элемент `listbox`а открывается новая форма, но также это  происходит(ложное срабатывание) после заполнение `listbox`а командой `listBox4.DataSource = id`

открытие

```
private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = listBox2.Text;
    selectedID = a;
    Form f2 = new Carta();
    f2.Show();
    listBox2.ClearSelected();
    // Clipboard.SetText(a);
}
```

Как исправить ложное открытие?

Comment: WinForms `string a = listBox2.Text;
            selectedID = a;
            Form f2 = new Carta();
            f2.Show();
            listBox2.ClearSelected();`

Comment: самопроизвольно открывается  последний добавлены элемент, я так понимаю, что он выделяется и происходит действие

Comment: Сперва привязывайте источник данных, а уже потом подписывайтесь на событие. Если это происходит неоднократно, то сперва отписывайтесь от события.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суть решения заключается в том, чтобы отключить код, который реагирует на изменение выбранного индекса.

Есть вариант с привязывание и отвязываением событий:

```
listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged -= listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged;
listBox2.DataSource = new List<string>
{
    "qwerty1",
    "qwerty2",
    "qwerty3"
};
listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

А можно использовать переменную flag:

```
private bool isManualSetData = false;

...

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!isManualSetData)
    {
        Form f2 = new Form();
        f2.Show();
    }
}

...

isManualSetData = true;
listBox1.DataSource = new List<string>
{
    "qwerty1",
    "qwerty2",
    "qwerty3"
};
isManualSetData = false;
```